# Run node-red without web interface

Tags: node-red

I'm new to node-red. I'm using mqtt and few other stuff.

After it is done, I dont want to waste resources in the website that i will not use, just processing the flows that I have done previously, and expose the website only when I need to do changes to those flows.

You can protect it with a firewall but this is not what i want, and resources would be used anyways.

I'm using a raspberry with ubuntu 20.04, and node-red website is accessible only with https.

The question is if it possible to run node-red without the web interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After googling for a while i was able to find it.

You need to change 3 lines in settings.js inside your home .node-red directory

Edit the file and add/changes this lines:

```
// By default, the Node-RED UI is available at http://localhost:1880/
// The following property can be used to specify a different root path.
// If set to false, this is disabled.
//httpAdminRoot: '/admin',
httpAdminRoot: false,
// Some nodes, such as HTTP In, can be used to listen for incoming http requests.
// By default, these are served relative to '/'. The following property
// can be used to specifiy a different root path. If set to false, this is
// disabled.
//httpNodeRoot: '/red-nodes',
httpNodeRoot: false,
// The following property can be used to disable the editor. The admin API
// is not affected by this option. To disable both the editor and the admin
// API, use either the httpRoot or httpAdminRoot properties
disableEditor: true,
```

Then restart node-red with

```
node-red-restart
```

from command line